# An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions, what to do?

Tags: c#, sockets, visual-studio-2012, sniffer

i am working on a school project. i am trying to make a sniffer.
in school the project works but in my house there is a problem.
this is the exception it throws me:"An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions"
this is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;

namespace MJsniffer
{
    public enum Protocol
    {
        TCP = 6,
        UDP = 17,
        Unknown = -1
    };

    public partial class MJsnifferForm : Form
    {
        private Socket mainSocket;                          //The socket which captures all incoming packets
        private byte[] byteData = new byte[4096];
        private bool bContinueCapturing = false;            //A flag to check if packets are to be captured or not

        private delegate void AddTreeNode(TreeNode node);

        public MJsnifferForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cmbInterfaces.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Select an Interface to capture the packets.", "MJsniffer", 
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error); //THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS.
                return;
            }
            try
            {
                if (!bContinueCapturing)        
                {
                    //Start capturing the packets...

                    btnStart.Text = "&Stop";enter code here

                    bContinueCapturing = true;

                    //For sniffing the socket to capture the packets has to be a raw socket, with the
                    //address family being of type internetwork, and protocol being IP
                    mainSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                        SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IP);

                    //Bind the socket to the selected IP address
                    mainSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(cmbInterfaces.Text), 0));

                    //Set the socket  options
                    mainSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP,            //Applies only to IP packets
                                               SocketOptionName.HeaderIncluded, //Set the include the header
                                               true);                           //option to true

                    byte[] byTrue = new byte[4] {1, 0, 0, 0};
                    byte[] byOut = new byte[4]{1, 0, 0, 0}; //Capture outgoing packets

                    //Socket.IOControl is analogous to the WSAIoctl method of Winsock 2
                    mainSocket.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll,              //Equivalent to SIO_RCVALL constant
                                                                                //of Winsock 2
                                         byTrue,                                    
                                         byOut);

                    //Start receiving the packets asynchronously
                    mainSocket.BeginReceive(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None,
                        new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), null);
                }
                else
                {
                    btnStart.Text = "&Start";
                    bContinueCapturing = false;
                    //To stop capturing the packets close the socket
                    mainSocket.Close ();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "MJsniffer", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private void OnReceive(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                int nReceived = mainSocket.EndReceive(ar);

                //Analyze the bytes received...

                ParseData (byteData, nReceived);

                if (bContinueCapturing)     
                {
                    byteData = new byte[4096];

                    //Another call to BeginReceive so that we continue to receive the incoming
                    //packets
                    mainSocket.BeginReceive(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None,
                        new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), null);
                }
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException)
            {
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "MJsniffer", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }            
        }

        private void ParseData(byte[] byteData, int nReceived)
        {
            TreeNode rootNode = new TreeNode();

            //Since all protocol packets are encapsulated in the IP datagram
            //so we start by parsing the IP header and see what protocol data
            //is being carried by it
            IPHeader ipHeader = new IPHeader(byteData, nReceived);

            TreeNode ipNode = MakeIPTreeNode(ipHeader);
            rootNode.Nodes.Add(ipNode);

            //Now according to the protocol being carried by the IP datagram we parse 
            //the data field of the datagram
            switch (ipHeader.ProtocolType)
            {
                case Protocol.TCP:

                    TCPHeader tcpHeader = new TCPHeader(ipHeader.Data,              //IPHeader.Data stores the data being 
                                                                                    //carried by the IP datagram
                                                        ipHeader.MessageLength);//Length of the data field                    

                    TreeNode tcpNode = MakeTCPTreeNode(tcpHeader);

                    rootNode.Nodes.Add(tcpNode);

                    //If the port is equal to 53 then the underlying protocol is DNS
                    //Note: DNS can use either TCP or UDP thats why the check is done twice
                    if (tcpHeader.DestinationPort == "53" || tcpHeader.SourcePort == "53")
                    {
                        TreeNode dnsNode = MakeDNSTreeNode(tcpHeader.Data, (int)tcpHeader.MessageLength);
                        rootNode.Nodes.Add(dnsNode);
                    }

                    break;

                case Protocol.UDP:

                    UDPHeader udpHeader = new UDPHeader(ipHeader.Data,              //IPHeader.Data stores the data being 
                                                                                    //carried by the IP datagram
                                                       (int)ipHeader.MessageLength);//Length of the data field                    

                    TreeNode udpNode = MakeUDPTreeNode(udpHeader);

                    rootNode.Nodes.Add(udpNode);

                    //If the port is equal to 53 then the underlying protocol is DNS
                    //Note: DNS can use either TCP or UDP thats why the check is done twice
                    if (udpHeader.DestinationPort == "53" || udpHeader.SourcePort == "53")
                    {

                        TreeNode dnsNode = MakeDNSTreeNode(udpHeader.Data,
                                                           //Length of UDP header is always eight bytes so we subtract that out of the total 
                                                           //length to find the length of the data
                                                           Convert.ToInt32(udpHeader.Length) - 8);  
                        rootNode.Nodes.Add(dnsNode);
                    }

                    break;

                case Protocol.Unknown:
                    break;
            }

            AddTreeNode addTreeNode = new AddTreeNode(OnAddTreeNode);

            rootNode.Text = ipHeader.SourceAddress.ToString() + "-" +
                ipHeader.DestinationAddress.ToString();

            //Thread safe adding of the nodes
            treeView.Invoke(addTreeNode, new object[] {rootNode});
        }

        //Helper function which returns the information contained in the IP header as a
        //tree node
        private TreeNode MakeIPTreeNode(IPHeader ipHeader)
        {
            TreeNode ipNode = new TreeNode();

            ipNode.Text = "IP";            
            ipNode.Nodes.Add ("Ver: " + ipHeader.Version);
            ipNode.Nodes.Add ("Header Length: " + ipHeader.HeaderLength);
            ipNode.Nodes.Add ("Differntiated Services: " + ipHeader.DifferentiatedServices);
            ipNode.Nodes.Add("Total Length: " + ipHeader.TotalLength);
            ipNode.Nodes.Add("Identification: " + ipHeader.Identification);
            ipNode.Nodes.Add("Flags: " + ipHeader.Flags);
            ipNode.Nodes.Add("Fragmentation Offset: " + ipHeader.FragmentationOffset);
            ipNode.Nodes.Add("Time to live: " + ipHeader.TTL);
            switch (ipHeader.ProtocolType)
            {
                case Protocol.TCP:
                    ipNode.Nodes.Add ("Protocol: " + "TCP");
                    break;
                case Protocol.UDP:
                    ipNode.Nodes.Add ("Protocol: " + "UDP");
                    break;
                case Protocol.Unknown:
                    ipNode.Nodes.Add ("Protocol: " + "Unknown");
                    break;
            }
            ipNode.Nodes.Add("Checksum: " + ipHeader.Checksum);
            ipNode.Nodes.Add("Source: " + ipHeader.SourceAddress.ToString());
            ipNode.Nodes.Add("Destination: " + ipHeader.DestinationAddress.ToString());

            return ipNode;
        }

        //Helper function which returns the information contained in the TCP header as a
        //tree node
        private TreeNode MakeTCPTreeNode(TCPHeader tcpHeader)
        {
            TreeNode tcpNode = new TreeNode();

            tcpNode.Text = "TCP";

            tcpNode.Nodes.Add("Source Port: " + tcpHeader.SourcePort);
            tcpNode.Nodes.Add("Destination Port: " + tcpHeader.DestinationPort);
            tcpNode.Nodes.Add("Sequence Number: " + tcpHeader.SequenceNumber);

            if (tcpHeader.AcknowledgementNumber != "")
                tcpNode.Nodes.Add("Acknowledgement Number: " + tcpHeader.AcknowledgementNumber);

            tcpNode.Nodes.Add("Header Length: " + tcpHeader.HeaderLength);
            tcpNode.Nodes.Add("Flags: " + tcpHeader.Flags);
            tcpNode.Nodes.Add("Window Size: " + tcpHeader.WindowSize);
            tcpNode.Nodes.Add("Checksum: " + tcpHeader.Checksum);

            if (tcpHeader.UrgentPointer != "")
                tcpNode.Nodes.Add("Urgent Pointer: " + tcpHeader.UrgentPointer);

            return tcpNode;
        }

        //Helper function which returns the information contained in the UDP header as a
        //tree node
        private TreeNode MakeUDPTreeNode(UDPHeader udpHeader)
        {           
            TreeNode udpNode = new TreeNode();

            udpNode.Text = "UDP";
            udpNode.Nodes.Add("Source Port: " + udpHeader.SourcePort);
            udpNode.Nodes.Add("Destination Port: " + udpHeader.DestinationPort);
            udpNode.Nodes.Add("Length: " + udpHeader.Length);
            udpNode.Nodes.Add("Checksum: " + udpHeader.Checksum);

            return udpNode;
        }

        //Helper function which returns the information contained in the DNS header as a
        //tree node
        private TreeNode MakeDNSTreeNode(byte[] byteData, int nLength)
        {
            DNSHeader dnsHeader = new DNSHeader(byteData, nLength);

            TreeNode dnsNode = new TreeNode();

            dnsNode.Text = "DNS";
            dnsNode.Nodes.Add("Identification: " + dnsHeader.Identification);
            dnsNode.Nodes.Add("Flags: " + dnsHeader.Flags);
            dnsNode.Nodes.Add("Questions: " + dnsHeader.TotalQuestions);
            dnsNode.Nodes.Add("Answer RRs: " + dnsHeader.TotalAnswerRRs);
            dnsNode.Nodes.Add("Authority RRs: " + dnsHeader.TotalAuthorityRRs);
            dnsNode.Nodes.Add("Additional RRs: " + dnsHeader.TotalAdditionalRRs);

            return dnsNode;
        }

        private void OnAddTreeNode(TreeNode node)
        {
            treeView.Nodes.Add(node);
        }

        private void SnifferForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string strIP = null;

            IPHostEntry HosyEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry((Dns.GetHostName()));
            if (HosyEntry.AddressList.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (IPAddress ip in HosyEntry.AddressList)
                {
                    strIP = ip.ToString();
                    cmbInterfaces.Items.Add(strIP);
                }
            }   
        }

        private void SnifferForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (bContinueCapturing)
            {
                mainSocket.Close();
            }
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());


        }

        private void treeView_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void treeView2_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I marked the problematic row with "//THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS."

Comment: Could be as simple as a permissions issue, have you tried running your compiled application via right click > Run as administrator?

Comment: i dont have that option when i right click on visual studio.
but i do have that option in other times.

Comment: Well, I had a quick search and using the term "my code" is pretty disingenuous isn't it. Here's a previous question about the exact same issue with the exact same code (which was taken from https://code.google.com/p/grsniffer/)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15378876/c-sharp-socket-exception-an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forbi?rq=1

It's a permissions issue.

Comment: I doubt that line is where the exception is thrown. Debug your code and find the correct line. Also, please reduce your code sample to the bare minimum.

Comment: i did debug it, this is the last line that works and then it jumps to the catch

Answer (score 3):

You are required to have administrator rights in order to use raw sockets. Apparently, you aren't running this code under an account with administrator rights.

To fix this, run the code under an account with administrator rights.